# Passing parameters to WCF restful service with POST method

Tags: fiddler, wcf-rest, webinvoke

how can I use Fiddler to pass 2 parameters to a method with a signature like this :

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Login", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]        
    bool Login(string login, string password);
```

Any suggestion to change something in the method is welcome, but I have always to pass 2 string parameters.

Answer (score 2):

It is much easier to the services with WCFTestClient. Anyway, Fiddler has composer functionality which can be used to test any http calls.

[image]

Request Headers should look like below. Just change SOAPAction accordingly.

```
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IService/Login"
Host: localhost:2045
Content-Length: 179
Expect: 100-continue
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
```

And request body:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><Login xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"><login>sdf</login><password>sdf</password></Login></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```